# Editing multiplease lines of a text file in php for lines matching different words

Tags: php

I need to edit multiple lines in a text file with php script. actually it is a include configuration file of my own php application which has different options values stored as constants in it. And I want that users can change these muliple options with help of html form and the php script runs at backend and edit this configuration text file multiple lines by matching the options words in lines. i am using a code for single line replacement till now, but i am not able to understand how i can make this for replacement of different multiple lines at a single-shot by matching different words,. following is my code which i am using for single line replacement for single word matching.
here rs.php file is that text file which needs to be edited
and rs.tmp is the temporary file i am using

```
$reading = fopen('rs.php', 'r');
$writing = fopen('rs.tmp', 'w');

$replaced = false;

while (!feof($reading)) {
    $line = fgets($reading);
    if (stristr($line,'SEND_SMS')) {
        $line = "define('SEND_SMS','$sms');\n";
        $replaced = true;
    }

    fputs($writing, $line);
}
fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
// might as well not overwrite the file if we didn't replace anything
if ($replaced) 
{
    rename('rs.tmp', 'rs.php');
} else {
    unlink('rs.tmp');
}
```

How I can do replacement of multiple lines in one shot by matching diffrent words.... pleas help

The content of my options text file rs.php is as follows:-

```
<?php

### For allowing send SMS or not - 1 is allow and 0 is not allowed
define('SEND_SMS','0');

### No. of exams/ assessment for any particular FA - select from 1 to 4
define('NO_OF_TESTS','1');

## color of webpages
define('COLOR','green');

?>
```

Comment: <?php         
define('SEND_SMS','0');                                  define('NO_OF_TESTS_IN_FA','0');                                                 define('COLOR_OF_PAGE','green');

Comment: Iwnnay : Actually that is a part of code which changes the option of SEND_SMS value from 0 to 1 which user selects using a html form which i am showing here, there are some other options also like webpage colors and no of tests etc etc. I need help for the code which can change/ replace other lines of the files also depending upton the user selection like the color of page and other option values... I hope now my question is clear